# Autochange values of a variable outside a while loop in Python

Tags: python, loops, variables, while-loop

I do not really know how to correctly ask this question so please bear with me. So,

```
b=1

a=b

while (a<10):
    b+=1
    #a=b
    print a, b
```

This returns an infinite loop UNLESS I remove the #. What I am asking is this: is there a way to UPDATE the value of var a without having to put "a=b" inside the loop? On my real script the value of a is a very big formula and I do not want to carry it inside every nested loop because it looks ugly. I tried using "global a" but still it does not work. Any ideas?

EDIT

As suggested here is the real code:

```
def generator(tar_cal):
    meal_1=["oats", "egg whites", "green apple"]
    meal_1_cal=tar_cal*0.27

    oats_min=50
    egg_whites_min=4
    green_apple_min=1
    sum1=(8*9+11*4+60*4)*oats_min/100 + (0.1*9+3.6*4+0.2*4)*egg_whites_min + (0.3*9+0.5+4+20.6*4)*green_apple_min
    while not (meal_1_cal <= sum1):
        if oats_min<100:
            oats_min+=10
            sum1=(8*9+11*4+60*4)*oats_min/100 + (0.1*9+3.6*4+0.2*4)*egg_whites_min + (0.3*9+0.5+4+20.6*4)*green_apple_min 
        elif egg_whites_min<8:
            egg_whites_min+=1
            sum1=(8*9+11*4+60*4)*oats_min/100 + (0.1*9+3.6*4+0.2*4)*egg_whites_min + (0.3*9+0.5+4+20.6*4)*green_apple_min
        else:
            green_apple_min+=1
            sum1=(8*9+11*4+60*4)*oats_min/100 + (0.1*9+3.6*4+0.2*4)*egg_whites_min + (0.3*9+0.5+4+20.6*4)*green_apple_min
    print "meal 1: %d grams kouaker, %d egg whites, %d green apple(s) " %(oats_min, egg_whites_min, green_apple_min)


generator(2000)
```

Comment: There are multiple ways to update the value, so unless you provide the actual code and the real problem - it is difficult to recommend the correct approach.

Comment: numbers are copied by value, you could use a class /object to copy by reference

Comment: I think the code review site is a better place for your question.

Comment: as you can see, the sum1 variable has to be added into every "if" statement in order to be updated so that the while loop expression makes sense. Adding sum1 every time looks ugly because of the length of the formula. Is there a prettier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create separate function, and parameterize the formula. Try something like this:

```
def calculate_value(oats=50, egg_whites=4, green_apple=1):
   oats_value = (8*9+11*4+60*4)*oats_min/100
   egg_whites_value = (0.1*9+3.6*4+0.2*4)*egg_whites
   green_apple = (0.3*9+0.5+4+20.6*4)*green_apple  
   return (oats_value, egg_whites_value, green_apple)
```

Now, in your actual method, simply call it with the values:

```
def generator(tar_cal):
    meal_1=["oats", "egg whites", "green apple"]
    meal_1_cal=tar_cal*0.27
    oats_min=50
    egg_whites_min=4
    green_apple_min=1
    sum1 = sum(calculate_value(oats_min, egg_whites_min, green_apple_min))
    while not (meal_1_cal <= sum1):
        if oats_min<100:
            oats_value = oats_min += 10
            sum1=sum(calculate_value(oats=oats_value))
        elif egg_whites_min<8:
            egg_whites = egg_whites_min+=1
            sum1=sum(calculate_value(egg_whites=egg_whites))
        else:
            green_apple = green_apple_min+=1
            sum1 = sum(calculate_value(green_apple=green_apple))
    print "meal 1: %d grams kouaker, %d egg whites, %d green apple(s) " %(oats_min, egg_whites_min, green_apple_min)


generator(2000)
```

Comment: This is needlessly complicated (the `sum` could've been moved into the `calculate_value` function) and also wrong because you only pass 1 parameter to your `calculate_value` function instead of all three.

Comment: I believe this is the best solution. Thanks

Comment: @Rawing the reason the three values are returned separately is if they are needed individually.

Answer (score 0):

In python Integers are copied by value, instead of reference. So if you want to copy by reference you have to define those in a python list.try this code

```
#python 3.4
b=[1]

a=b

while (a[0]<10):
    b[0]=b[0]+1
    #a=b
    print(a[0], b[0])
```